# Function to return only after the array's fetch loop is completed

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

The following function returns an array of `PFObjects`. The problem I am having is that it when the function reaches the return point the `for object in object` loop is not yet completed and for that reason the function is returning an empty array.

Is there a way to only return after the loop is completed and the PF array is populated?

```
func getSelectedPosts() -> [PFObject] {

    println("RUN GET SH")

    var fetchResults = [PFObject]()

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
    var relation = user.relationForKey("followingPosts")
    var query = relation.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            for object in object!
            {
                fetchResults.append(object as! PFObject)
            }
            // NEED TO RETURN HERE, THAT IS WHEN THE LOOP IS DONE AND THE ARRAY POPULATED
        }
        else
        {
        // ERROR
        }
    })

    return fetchResults
 }
```

Comment: your for-in is within a closure and return will be corresponding to this closure

Comment: The return wont be recognised inside that closure. Also, that closure is a mandatory part of the PFQuery and I cannot change that if that is what you mean. Not sure if I understood your suggestion correctly.

Comment: DOWN VOTES - I am keen to find out more why this question is getting down voted and avoid the mistake of asking questions like this in the future. Any guidance will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the function needed one parameter to fetch the result. Follow the below link

[Completion Handlers](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/)

Answer (score 1):

Following umakanta suggestion and the closures explained [here](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/) i could get it to work as i intended with closures.

**Function**

```
    func getSelectedPosts(result: (object: [PFObject]?, error: NSError? -> Void){   
        println("RUN GET SH")

        var fetchResults = [PFObject]()
        var err = NSError()

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
        var relation = user.relationForKey("followingPosts")
        var query = relation.query()
        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil
            {
                for object in object!
                {
                    fetchResults.append(object as! PFObject)
                }
                result(object: fetchResults, error: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                println("ERROR - getSelectedPosts \(error)")
                result(object: nil, error: error)
            }
        })
    }
```

**Function call**

```
        getSelectedPosts { (object) -> Void in
            if error != nil
            {
               // deal with error
            }
            else
            {
               // use fetched object
            }
        }
```